# Following django form submission, redirect to page using newly created pk

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to redirect the user to edit details of a task after task submission, but am having troubles redirecting to a page based on the newly created pk.  Each view works without the return HttpResponseRedirect line.  I have also tried arge=(instance.id) and kwargs=(instance.id) for the variable.

views.py

```
...
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseServerError, HttpResponseForbidden, Http404, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404,render
...

def new_task(request):
    ...
    ...
    task.save()
    instance = task.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('task_values', instance.id))

def task_values(request, task_id):
   ...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns += patterns('core.views_entry',               
                   #Task viewing/editing
                   (r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/$','task_values'),
                   (r'^enter/$','new_task'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('task_values', kwargs={'task_id': instance.id}))
```

Also note that you don't need to save the task twice.

**Edit** OK, there's another problem. You haven't given your URLs specific names, which means that the only way to identify them is to pass the fully qualified view name:

```
reverse('core.views_entry.task_values', kwargs=...)
```

Or, better, use the the `url()` function to name your URL:

```
url(r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/$','task_values', name='task_values'),
```

and you can use the original version I gave above.

Note that the error isn't telling you it's going to `enter/<id>/`, just that in that view it's trying to create the reverse URL for the redirection and failing.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the saving twice call. But I am getting 'NoReverseMatch at /enter/' and "Reverse for 'task_values' with arguments'()' and keyword arguments '{'task_id':119L}' not found", I want to redirect to /task/{instance.id}/ and it seems to be trying to go to /enter/{instance.id}.  If I modify the url conf to have both be enter, the pk still is not passing.